# LyX: how to make two "examples" not separated by a different environment?

Tags: environments, lyx

I use LyX for some time now, but have not figured out how to put two "examples" (or exercises or theorems etc.) one after the other without having to separate them by a different environment.

What happens: say I'm in the "example" environment and finished writing example No 1. I hit enter to start a new paragraph. LyX then allows me to choose a *different* environment like "standard text" starting from the new paragraph, but I'm unable to start a new example No 2.

I hope someone knows a simple solution.

Comment: @darthbith: Indeed, I didn't see that when posting. Funny that it was asked just about a month earlier.

Comment: Yeah, I only noticed it now because another duplicate was asked today! :-)

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/632952/193546 for LyX 2.3.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

At the end of the first example add a  --Separator-- (from the list of text environments).

[image]

Comment: @Michael: Never mind. I had been using LyX for years until I discovered that `--Separator--` actually is a layout. Before that I did consider it as a *visual* element to group stuff within the layout menu.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/632952/193546 for LyX 2.3.