# Two consecutive remarks on LyX

Tags: lists, lyx, environments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Two math sections of the same type in a row?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39784/two-math-sections-of-the-same-type-in-a-row)

I am new to lyx, and I am searching for a way to create two remarks one after the other.

When I create a remark, the only way that I found so far to add the second remark is to create a new line (in standard environment) with space in it and then at the line after  can create the second remark.

What I want to do is:

> Remark 1: 
>   Remark 2:

like enumeration, but with remarks. (Could be in TeX/LaTeX if there is no solution in LyX)

Can any one help?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) Your post was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Comment: Which document class are you using that defines a "Remark" environment? It's possible using a regular list and setting the label display using [`enumitem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem).

Comment: @Werner It's a theorem-like thing, at least it's found in the *Theorems (AMS)* module. mestrebisli: Your problem appears to be the same as http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39784/, see if any of the solutions there help. If so, we'll probably close this question as a duplicate, to keep things tidy.

Comment: Hi Torbjørn, this solved my problem!
Thanks!

Comment: No problem, glad it helped. A small tip regarding comments. You've probably noticed that you get notifications about comments to your question, but if you want to make sure other commenters are notified, write `@<username>` in the comment, like I did with Werner in my previous comment. There is tab-completion of usernames, so when you start writing e.g. `@Torbjørn T.`, a small pop-up with my username should appear, and you can press the tab key to add the rest.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/632952/193546 for LyX 2.3.