# Writing definition, theorem, lemma more than once in Lyx

Tags: lyx

I am trying to make a list of definitions and theorems and everything, however, I can't write definition, theorem, lemma etc. consecutively.  For example I write a definition, I press enter twice , so it goes back to standard and I want to write one more definition, so I click definition and it goes back to my previous definition and it doesn't let me write consecutively the same type. And  the same problem occurs for every type of mathematical concept that I have.

How can I write consecutive environments of the same type?

Comment: Does this help: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39784/32374?

Comment: Glad it helped! :-)

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/632952/193546 for LyX 2.3.